# Nothing showing in the render

Tags: rendering

So I was trying to make renders for my game, and when I go to render the image or press F12, I get this.

[image]

When I choose render image or press F12 this happens. There is literally nothing in the render and it's just a grey screen. I thought maybe the render is just taking a long time to finish, So I started a 5 minute timer, the 5 minutes pass, and it's still the same grey screen.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I tried searching through tons of tutorials on YouTube, but I didn't find anything about this problem, So I have to rely on the Blender Stack Exchange.

Are there any settings I need to change?
Any modifications needed in the camera properties or something?
Is it about my GPU driver? I certainly hope not.

I really wanna fix this problem, because of this, I can't really do anything with Blender to make my game

Also, here's the .blend file:
[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? Make it as simple and light as possible: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I added the file at the very bottom of the post.

Comment: make sure your camara is pointing at the object!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object called *Cube.006* is hiding your scene but it's invisible for preview, make it invisible for render as well:

[image]

Comment: Oh wow! It's actually fixed, Thank you so much! Also if you are wondering why there aren't any textures, This is just the first asset for the game, and I am just using a render with no textures as a test/placeholder.